# When I try SQLite on iOS, INSERT and UPDATE does not work

Tags: ios, sqlite

I createed a table in `user.db`, this file is in my xcode project folder.

```
create table user (uid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT, username, mobile);
```

Next, in the app delegate `.m` file, I insert two rows, then I query `select * from user` and print it.

However, use statement and sqlite3_exec, the insertions are not successful, and there are no errors at all. `user.db` has 3 rows I inserted from sqlite command line. When I run this app, it prints 5 rows of data, 2 rows are inserted by me, but when I query in sqlite command line, there are still 3 rows, the two newer rows are not committed?

I also run `sqlite3_get_autocommit`, and find out `autocommit=1`, so what have I missed to cause this to happen?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  NSString* file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"user" ofType:@"db"];
  sqlite3* database = NULL;
  if(sqlite3_open([file UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
  {
    NSLog(@"database open successfully.");
    // stmt

    // int autocommit = sqlite3_get_autocommit(database);

    sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
    static char * sql = "insert into user (username, mobile) values('xxxx', '5555555');commit;";
    int success = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
    if(success != SQLITE_OK)
    {
      NSLog(@"create stmt failed");
    }
    success = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    if(success != SQLITE_OK)
    {
      NSLog(@"insert failed");
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

    sqlite3_exec(database, "begin;insert into user (username, mobile) values('yyyy', '666666');commit;", NULL, NULL, 0);

    // insert 
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc = sqlite3_exec(database, "select * from user", MyCallback, 0, &zErrMsg);
    if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
    }
  }
  sqlite3_close(database);
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: This is not related to Xcode by any means. And the name of Apple's mobile operating system is "iOS", not "IOS". IOS is something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

You can't update databases stored in the app resources.  Try copying the database to your app's Document or Library folder and then updating the database there.

Comment: Hello rekle, where can the `app Document folder`be found please? thanx in advance.