# Core Data: default state of autocommit

Tags: ios, core-data, autocommit

I'm wondering what is default state of autocommmit in iOS Core Data and if it's possible to change it. I couldn't find any mentions in official documentation. On SO I've found only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100449/when-i-try-sqlite-on-ios-insert-and-update-does-not-work) It's said, that native sqlite framework has low-level function to determine the state of autocommit.
Maybe it's possible to improve a performance by unsetting autocommit if it's set by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Data does not have auto-commit.  You must save your context.  Now, if you are using UIManagedDocument, it's different... because it does have auto-save, but you still have to tell it that it has dirty data so it knows to auto-save.